# How do you use Opera's built-in IRC client?

Tags: opera, irc

I've been trying to use the built-in IRC client, but failed in all attempts. I'm posting this question a bit late, so I don't exactly remember what the error message was, but it was in the lines of the user not providing enough details. I've skipped providing real name and email address at the first run - could this be the cause?

I hope someone can provide a concise guide to setting it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spanish tutorial at http://my.opera.com/espanol/forums/topic.dml?id=90175 reads:

> 3º. Escribimos un nombre cualquiera y
>   una dirección de correo cualquiera (no
>   es obligado ni recomendable rellenar
>   los campos con datos reales).
>   Pinchamos en "Siguiente".

Translated here for you:

> 3°, Write any name and any email
>   address (not forced nor recommended to
>   use real data in these fields). Click
>   next.

It seems that you should provide at least any data over here, and remember that the usernames on irc are at least 3 characters in length, and email addresses should be in email style format, like: you@mail.com

Anyway, there are several ways to get into IRC channels, opera channels are majorly in Freenode, which can be reached by almost any IRC capable client, like Pidgin, xChat, irssi, etc.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I found that without name and email, IRC won't work.

Comment: Email is optional as long as you never give that field keyboard focus. It is a known bug.